# Check $|\{X:X \subseteq \{1,2,..,n\} \land \{1,4\} \subseteq X \land\{3,6\} \cap X = \phi\}|$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Check $\forall n$ value of $|\{X:X \subseteq \{1,2,..,n\} \land \{1,4\} \subseteq X \land\{3,6\} \cap X = \phi\}|$

Well, I'm not sure how to approach this question. But I do believe that I need to check what happends when $n=1,2,..6$ and what happens when $n \ge 7$

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Look first at the case $n\ge 6$. So $X$ must contain 1 and 4 and must not contain 3 or 6. Every other value, such as 2, 5, 7, 8, ... can be either in or out. There are $n-4$ other values, so there are $2^{n-4}$ possible sets $X$. It is trivial to deal with $n<6$.

Comment: @almagest I understand why it must contain $1,4$, but why it must not contain 3 OR 6? I think it must not contain 3 AND 6. So we stay with $1,2,4,5,7,8...,n$ Which means $2^{n-2}$

Comment: The intersection of the sets $X$ and $\{3,6\}$ is empty. If 3 was in $X$, but 6 was not, the intersection would be non-empty.